# Convert table from column wise to row wise format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table like the following:

```
entity field_1 field_2 field_3
1      A 
2              B
3              E       C
```

and I have to convert the table to the following structure:

```
entity param_id     param_value
1      paramId_1    A
2      paramId_2    B
3      ParamId_2    E
3      ParamId_3    C
```

If you observe the tables, the second table will be formed based on the data present in the first table. There are 3 columns for each entity in table 1. So table 2 can have at most 3 rows for 1 entity at most. The number of the rows will depend on the non null values present in the first table.

So how can this be achieved in Oracle? I tried searching in Google, but could not find any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct application of `unpivot`. `null` values are ignored during this operation.

```
select entity,case when field='FIELD_1' then 'paramID_1' 
                   when field='FIELD_2' then 'paramID_2' 
                   when field='FIELD_3' then 'paramID_3' 
              end as param_id,
param_value              
from t
unpivot (param_value for field in (field_1,field_2,field_3)) u
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a union all to achieve the same thing.

```
SELECT e.entity
     , e.param_id
     , param_value = e.field_1

FROM dbo.entity (NOLOCK) e 

UNION ALL 

SELECT e1.entity
     , e1.param_id
     , param_value = e1.field_2

FROM dbo.entity (NOLOCK) e1 

UNION ALL 

SELECT e2.entity
     , e2.param_id
     , param_value = e2.field_3

FROM dbo.entity (NOLOCK) e2
```